# Extract Max and Min values of a column from a table in the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have the following table:

```
ID  Bag Event       Count   Driver  Time
1   XYZ Pick-up     10      A1      10:30 AM
2   XYZ Trnsfr-out  10      A1      10:40 AM
3   XYZ Trnsfr-in   10      A2      10:40 AM
4   XYZ Drop        10      A2      10:50 AM
5   ABC Pick-up     10      B1      10:30 AM
6   ABC Trnsfr-out  10      B1      10:40 AM
7   ABC Trnsfr-in   10      B2      10:40 AM
8   ABC Trnsfr-out  10      B2      10:50 AM
```

Is there anyway I can get Drivers for MAX(ID) and MIN(ID) for a particular bag using the same query?

I have the following query now:

```
Select Bag, Count, Driver as FinalDriver,TIME from Bagtable where ID in  (Select Max(ID) from Bagtable Group By Bag)
```

The Result is

```
Bag Count   FinalDriver TIME
XYZ 10      A2          10:50 AM
ABC 10      B2          10:50 AM
```

I want the result to looks something like this:
The values for Initial driver should be obtained by using the min(ID) for a specific bag.

```
Bag Count   InitialDriver   FinalDriver TIME
XYZ 10      A1              A2          10:50 AM
ABC 10      B1              B2          10:50 AM
```

Kindly help me with the SQL for the above. Thanks

Comment: Are you using oracle or sql server 2008?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Since I wanted to know the logic, I tagged Oracle also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle (you tagged this question with both Oracle and SQL Server which are two different databases) you could use:

```
select bag,
       count,
       min(decode(id, min_bag_id, driver, null)) as initialdriver,
       min(decode(id, max_bag_id, driver, null)) as finaldriver,
       min(decode(id, max_bag_id, time, null)) as time
  from (select id,
               bag,
               count,
               driver,
               time,
               min(id) over(partition by bag) as min_bag_id,
               max(id) over(partition by bag) as max_bag_id
          from tbl)
 group by bag,
          count
```

Comment: You're missing an aggregate function to wrap the `decode` statements. You probably meant to use `min(decode(...))` or `max(decode(...))`

Comment: I guess the subquery needs an alias. Thank you and this works

Comment: @vkr no problem. In SQL server all inline views require an alias, in Oracle they don't

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `aggregate` functions.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/970ec/1)

```
select b.bag, max(b.count) as count, 
max(case when time = mintime then driver end) as initialdriver,
max(case when time = maxtime then driver end) as finaldriver,
max(x.maxtime) as time 
from 
(select bag, min(TIME) as mintime, max(time) as maxtime
from Bagtable 
group by bag) x
join Bagtable b
on x.bag = b.bag
group by b.bag
```

Comment: TIME can contain NULL in the table. So its difficult to aggregate on TIME

Answer (score 0):

Try below sql:

```
SELECT BAG, 
       COUNT, 
       MAX(DECODE(MIN_RN,1,DRIVER,NULL)) INITIALDRIVER, 
       MAX(DECODE(MAX_RN,1,DRIVER,NULL)) FINALDRIVER,
       MAX(TIME) TIME
  FROM (SELECT BAG,
               COUNT,
               DRIVER,
               TIME,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BAG ORDER BY ID )     MIN_RN,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BAG ORDER BY ID DESC) MAX_RN
          FROM TAB)
 GROUP BY BAG,COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question as both Oracle and SQL Server.  Two different beasts as far as capabilities are concerned.

Here's an Oracle solution using some of it's aggregate functions:

```
select b.bag
     , max(b.count) as count
     , min(driver) keep (dense_rank first order by id) initial_driver
     , min(driver) keep (dense_rank LAST order by id) Final_driver
     , min(time) keep (dense_rank LAST order by id) time
from bagtable b
group by b.bag
```

You can see the [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d885d/3)

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on Brian's logic in SQL

```
select bag,
   count,
   min(case id when min_bag_id then driver else null end) as initialdriver,
   min(case id when max_bag_id then driver else null end) as finaldriver,
   min(case id when max_bag_id then tm else null end) as time
  from (select id,
           bag,
           count,
           driver,
           tm,
           min(id) over(partition by bag) as min_bag_id,
           max(id) over(partition by bag) as max_bag_id
          from bagtable) a
 group by bag,
          count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple query to get the required output

select Bag,max(id),min(id) from Bagtable group by Bagtable;